# How do I scale my SVG to fit the size of its container div in d3?

Tags: html, css, svg

Is there a way to make my SVG scale to the dimensions of `#mapDiv`?

HTML:

```
<div id="mapDiv">
    <svg id="mapSVG" width="960" height="600" viewbox="0 0"></svg>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var svg = d3.select("#mapSVG"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");
```

CSS:

```css
#mapDiv{
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 7px;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

#mapSVG{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I don't need the SVG to scale when the page is resized, by the way. As long as the SVG scales to the div size when the page loads, that's good enough for me.

Comment: you have to nest with another div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a CSS solution, simply give your `#mapDiv` a fixed `height` and `width`, and then have the `svg` element take up `100%` of both the width and height. This can be seen in the following:

```css
#mapDiv {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

#mapDiv > svg {
  border: 5px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="mapDiv">
  <svg id="mapSVG" width="960" height="600" viewbox="0 0 960 600">
  </svg>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)